# Reduce function returning assignment is throwing error (ESLint issue: no-return-assign)

Tags: javascript, return, eslint

My code (which works):

```
const calculateBalance = (coins) => {
  console.log('coins', coins);
  return coins.reduce((bal, coin) => (bal += parseInt(coin.balance)), 0);
};
```

Basically I just want to add up all the coin balances in my portfolio, however I'm getting an eslint error.

> Arrow function should not return assignment.

[image]

Googling I found this: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign

> One of the interesting, and sometimes confusing, aspects of JavaScript is that assignment can happen at almost any point. Because of this, an errant equals sign can end up causing assignment when the true intent was to do a comparison. This is especially true when using a return statement.

Here they have an example of what to do:

```
function doSomething() {
    return (foo = bar + 2);
}
```

However that is what I implemented, but eslint is still complaining... is there a way to update my code block above to make it pass?

Comment: Why are you even assigning (`+=`) there? A simple addition (`+`) would've done the same.

Comment: another question, what is `parseInt` (without base) doing?

Comment: Ah thanks, that did fix my actual code... I guess is there no case where `+=` could be fixed in this scenario? Anyways want to post your answer to the logic.

Comment: @NinaScholz you are right, I should have just used `Number()` in that part.

Comment: @NinaScholz parses in base 10 in most modern environments.

Comment: `bal + (+coin.balance)`? In any case, the `+=` is likely throwing issues to eslint, since you are assigning a value, while you should simply return it.

Comment: `bal + +coin.balance` is enough, if `coin.balance` is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the specs. (here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))

> The reduce() method applies a function against an *accumulator* and each
>   element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single
>   value.

---

As your `bal` is your *accumulator*, simply do `bal + parseInt(coin.balance)`